# Why do I have to assign function return value to a variable before operating on it in PHP

Tags: php, function, return-value

If I have a function like so:

```
function foo(){
 return array("hello" => "world");
}
```

I can't call the function and operate on the return value like so

```
$test = foo()["hello"];
```

Instead I have to break it up across two lines like so

```
$test = foo();
$test = $test["hello"];
```

Is there any way around this? If not, why does PHP enforce this. Also, if it's of any consequence, `foo()` actually returns a two dimensional array.

Comment: Just curious.. Could you share with us the reason why you were looking for a way around the existing method of assigning values from functions?

Comment: @Nonym +1 for not brazenly demanding to know why I asked the question

Comment: I am building some helper functions for dealing with sql queries. Sometimes the returned array is an array of a single column (ie the primary key), other times it is an array of an array of multiple columns (ie. first name, last name, nick name). In the case of the former, I just wanted to get the primary key in one shot.

Comment: So..like the one-liner if-then-else statement PHP already has..this ought to make a good new one-liner too.. Glad it appears to be in the works for PHP 5.4!

Comment: @Nonym I too like the `(<cond>) ? something : somethingElse`, and this should be a good addition

Answer (score 5, accepted):

PHP does not have array deferencing, the functionality you are asking for.

PHP 5.4, the upcoming version of PHP, does have this feature.

Comment: What's protocol in these situtations. Should I change the title to reflect this, or leave it be?

Answer (score -2):

I would think:

```
$test = foo();
```

Sets `$test` as the array, all you need to do is use it now:

```
echo $test["hello"] produces "world"
```

Comment: oh i see, you're trying to set a single variable with the value of "hello" from the function. My bad.

Comment: yes, I didn't go into too much detail, but the returned array is two dimensional, and I don't always need all the info